# How can I know what is in the core data

Tags: ios, swift, database, xcode, core-data

I'm currently working on a IOS project and using Core Data. My question is: 
Is there any tool or software I can use to see what data is in the Core Data when I'm running the project, and how to use them. Thank you so much!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40103564/1305067

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your app has run in the simulator it creates a persistent store file, you can find the file in your app's document's directory:

~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications

You can also check out [CoreDataEditor](https://github.com/ChristianKienle/Core-Data-Editor) or [CoreDataPro](https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility).

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools can make you efficient.

1. Parrot can help you enter the app sandbox easily，and you can download the app on the Mac Store.
2. You can use [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) exhibit your data .